# Branch point of pseudo-absolute function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

When working on complex analysis, I need a function that can act as an absolute function on the real axis, and I choose: $$\sqrt{z^2}$$ since I think this function does not violate the conditions for residue theorem to apply(is this true?).

But now I have no idea where its branch point is. Is it at the origin?

If so, I would like to take a branch cut at 45 degrees to infinity. Then what would the range of $\theta$ be?

Comment: What do mean by “this function does not violate the conditions for residue theorem to apply”? What do you mean by “branch point”? What is “upper right infinity”? Are there several infinities?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos 1. residue theorem requires the function to be analytic in a region except isolated points, so I said so. 2. As I know, square root function usually has a branch point(not sure if this function has). I think branch point is a clearly defined term. 3. “upper right infinity” is just a loose term that refers to the point which a branch cut starting at origin at 45 degrees would extend to. I shall edit this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this will answer your question, but I will try it anyway.

The only continuous functions $f\colon\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ such that $(\forall z\in\mathbb{C}):f^2(z)=z^2$ are $\pm\operatorname{Id}$. In fact, if $f$ is such a function, then$$(\forall z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}):\left(\frac{f(z)}z\right)^2=1.$$The number $1$ only has $2$ complex square roots: $\pm1$. Since $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is connected, and $z\mapsto\frac{f(z)}z$ is continuous, this function is either $1$ or $-1$. In other words, $f=\pm\operatorname{Id}$.

Comment: Thanks, surely this has given me some insight. Does your answer imply that the only choices of branch cut of this function(the one in the original question) is along either the negative or the positive real axis? If no, could you please clarify? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Szeto My answer doesn't mention real numbers at all and therefore it cannot possibly imply that. I don't understand your quest for branch cuts. They are introduced (as in the case of the square root) when we cannot define an analytic function globally. But in this case we can! The function $z^2$ has two analytic square roots: $z$ and $-z$.